# I would like to print all alphabet letters in the string below, however, I do not get an output when I run the code. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, string, alphanumeric

I would like to print all alphabet letters in the string below, however, I do not get an output when I run the code. Not even an error.  What am I doing wrong ?

```
        x='a14b8c789d45e17'
        for i in x:
            if i== '%s' %x:
        print(i)
```

#No output

Comment: You're comparing each character to the whole string. They'll never be equal unless the string is only 1 character long.

Comment: You probably want to test `if i.isalpha():`

Comment: `'%s' % x` is the same as just `x`.

Comment: I am actually working towards separating the string here into alphabets and digits. That is sorting it on the first occurrence of an alphabet. This is the output I would like a14;b8;c789;d45;e17. I am new to python and I've been struggling a bit. I saw an answer here suggesting the use of the re module but I would like to try to do it the hard way to help me understand how it works.

Comment: @Userio That information you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70509919/edit) into the question, as it's an necessary component of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently testing whether a single character equals the entire string. Instead, test each substring with the [`str.isalpha()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to test if they're letters or not:

```
x = 'a14b8c789d45e17'
for i in x:
    if i.isalpha():
       print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am actually working towards separating the string here into alphabets and digits. That is sorting it on the first occurrence of an alphabet. This is the output I would like [a14;b8;c789;d45;e17]. I am new to python and I've been struggling a bit. I saw an answer here suggesting the use of the re module but I would like to try to do it the hard way to help me understand how it works.

Comment: @Userio Well, you could maintain two variables: a `partial_word` string that you keep adding to until you encounter a new letter, and a `word_list` list that you add the `partial_word` value to once that's the case